# Problem Exporting Lattice Deform + B-Bones + Shape-Key Drivers

Tags: export, bones, drivers, lattice

I am not too advanced in all this, and my problem has really stumped me.

I have created a couple of characters from VeggieTales, using B-Bones, shape-keys, and Drivers to animate the mouth and a lattice deform to "rig the eyes". Here's what I've got:
[image]

I'm planning on using B-Bones as well to animate the whole body.

My problem is I want to be able to export these characters and import them into other Blender projects - maintaining the rigging and bones, etc.

I've tried exporting it on every format available in "File->Export", and none of them will import the object with the Lattices and the Bones + shape-key drivers, etc. Some of them even don't export everything in the scene (the eyes, for example, disappear).

**I'm wondering if there is a way to export such an object, maintaining parenting, Lattices, Bones, shape-keys, and drivers?**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Well, my Blender instructor actually told me how to fix this problem, so for those of you who are experiencing this same dilemma, try this:
Instead of exporting the file, just save a file with ONLY THE CHARACTER. Then, open the scene you want to "import" the character into. Go to File->Append. Here, find you blender file with the character, and click enter. Then, go to the "Object" Folder, select all with the "A" shortcut key, and click "Append" in the bottom right hand corner. That's it - the character, with the armature, lattices, and EVERYTHING is imported to your new scene!

Sorry about this. I hope someone else has this question, and finds this answer helpful! :D